# graphwin problems: 'list' object has no attribute 'onSaveClick'

Tags: python, zelle-graphics

I have (probably) a stupid error on my Python source code, then I search for a simple example to verify if it is my error not and I verify that this simple example/test does not work:

```py
from graphics import *

if __name__ == '__main__':

    def main():
        win = GraphWin('My Graphics', 250, 250) # specifies graphics window size 250x250
        g = Point(125, 125) # creates a Point object at x=125 y=125
        g.draw(win) # draws to the graphics window
        win.getMouse() # keep window up
        win.close()

    main()
```

It stops after g.draw(win) with this error:

```
AttributeError: 'list' object has no attribute 'onSaveClick'
```

I followed the code and I found that the error could be on class `GraphWin(tk.Canvas)`:
in the method:

```
def addItem(self, item):
    self.items.onSaveClick(item)
```

So it could be a bug.
Or have I misunderstand something?

Comment: I get a different error from the code in your question: `graphics.GraphicsError: getMouse in closed window` from the `win.getMouse() # keep window up` statement when I click on the close button that's on the window that appears when I run it. Please post a [mre] that corresponds to what you are asking.

Comment: in my case this example stops to work in he row before, it does not execute win.getMouse(). I am using Python 3.8.6, and you?

Comment: I'm using Python 3.8.10 and `graphics.py` v5.0. There's a point drawn in the middle of the window that appears.

Comment: You may have an old version of `graphics.py` because the `addItem()` method in my version has the line `self.items.append(item)` in it, not what's shown in your question. You can download the latest version (5.0) from [here](http://mcsp.wartburg.edu/zelle/python/graphics.py).

Answer (score 0):

In Python 3.8.6 graphics.py has an error inside, addItem() method has self.onSave(item) instead of self.items.append(item) so updating graphics.py to the 5.0 release solves the problem as pointed out by https://stackoverflow.com/users/355230/martineau